# Reference request: Origins of differential homological algebra

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, ho.history-overview

Differential homological algebra in its initial formulation is due to Eilenberg and Moore, who published the homological version of the Eilenberg–Moore spectral sequence in 1965 (and the cohomological version never), sufficiently long after its date of discovery that other accounts had been published in the meantime.

Paul Baum's 1962 thesis gives an account, but Moore had spoken on this theory at least as early as the 1959–60 *Seminaire Henri Cartan*, and in that appearance, says he and Eilenberg had worked it out jointly and it had already appeared in notes from the 1957–8 Princeton seminar on algebraic topology, which thus may be the earliest written source.

Are these still extant?

If so, **where can they be found**?

(This question has [also](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12396/the-origins-of-differential-homological-algebra) been posted on the History of Mathematics StackExchange without resounding success.)

Answer (score 6):

A copy of the mimeographed notes by J.C. Moore from the 1957-1958 Princeton Seminar on algebraic topology is in the Princeton University library: https://catalog.princeton.edu/catalog/1693293

It says "available upon request", although that seems limited to faculty and students. Perhaps some kind soul with access would be willing to scan the notes and place them online?

Comment: Speaking as a disinterested advocate for the public weal, I could get behind this idea.